# How to use a function which was declared in more than one header

Tags: c, function, header, header-files

so I have three files, **main.c, a.h, b.h**.
In all three files I have declared the following function

```
int test(int a, int b)
{
  if(a>b)
    return a;
  else return b;
}
```

Is there anyway I can use the function in the main program but from different locations (from a.h, then from b.h and then from main.c), because now I have this error: **error: redefinition of test**?

For a better understanding I will post the statement here:

> Write test() in two libraries, a.h and b.h. Include both libraries in a program. Investigate how can
> I use test() from a.h or b.h. What if I define test() also in the main program and I want to use the
> test() from main program, library a.h or b.h ?

The code in main.c is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
int test(int a, int b) //Function for showing the max
{
    if(a > b)
        return a;
    else return b;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    test(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

The code in a.h is identical with the one from b.h:

```
#ifndef CODE_a_H
#define CODE_a_H

int test(int a, int b) //Function for showing the max
{
    if(a > b)
        return a;
    else return b;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It seems you *defined* the function multiple times instead of just *declaring* the function like `int test(int a, int b);`.

Comment: Answer: don't place function *definitions* in header files. You can have as many *declarations* as you wish (so long as they are the same).

Comment: Header files should correspond to `.o` files that you link to the main program, you shouldn't actually define the function in the header file.

Comment: So there should also be `a.c` and `b.c`. You define the function in `a.c` and put a declaration in `a.h`.

Comment: @Barmar But the statement clearly says to put the function in the header, I know myself that that's a bit odd...

Comment: It's common to conflate the header file that declares all the functions in a library with the library itself.

Comment: Where's that assignment from? It's wierd. Header files are header files, not libraries.

Comment: `primtest` is not declared nor defined.

Comment: Is `test()` maybe supposed to be a *macro*?  That would make at least a little sense.  The quoted assignment makes no sense at all if `test()` is supposed to be a function.

Comment: If you want to also define `test()` in the main module (as well as in `a` and `b`), do not include or link `a` or `b` files. Otherwise, include one of  `a` and  `b` conditionally. But you are over-compilcating it - stick to the assignment.

Comment: It's an assignment for my university, but it doesn't make sense for me...In my knowledge I can't write the same function in two different headers

Comment: Well, maybe you're supposed to learn that this is (really) bad practice. What you could do is, define a preprocessor symbol (like `TEST_DEFINED`) along with `test()`. Surround the definition of `test()`in each header with `#ifndef TEST_DEFINED` and `#define TEST_DEFINED`.  Then it depends on the order of `include`s which definition ends up in your program.

Comment: `#ifdef USE_A #include "a.h" #else #include "b.h" #endif` each on a separate line.

Comment: We've assumed the C language because that's how you tagged the question.  Is it possible that the implementation language is instead meant to be C++, where you could use namespaces to differentiate between the different `test()` functions?

Comment: The problem is in C language, I think what @WeatherVane is saying has logic, I tried  his idea and is working, thank you

Comment: I would advise you to ask your instructor or their teaching assistant about the meaning of the exercise.  It certainly could be that @WeatherVane's is the approach that the exercise anticipates, but I would consider it a stretch to characterize that as "Includ[ing] both libraries in a program."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dubio pro reo.

Maybe you are supposed to learn something in this assignment. And the "something" could be "don't do this".

What you obviously learnt already is that this won't work because of duplicate symbols.

You can generate a working program with the help of the preprocessor.

Extend the definition of `test()` to

```
#ifndef CODE_a_H
#define CODE_a_H

#ifndef TEST_DEFINED
#define TEST_DEFINED
int test(int a, int b) //Function for showing the max
{
    if(a > b)
        return a;
    else return b;
}
#endif
#endif
```

Depending on the order of `#include` in your main program, the definition of the first file you include will end up in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the same function with same name in two different places(i mean .c files) and compile all the files.

If you want you can control that either with conditional compilation or compiling files separately and link based on the need.

primetest.h

```
#ifndef __PRIMETEST__
#define __PRIMETEST__

int primtest(int a, int b);

#endif /* __PRIMETEST__ */
```

primetest.c

```
int primtest(int a, int b) //Function for showing the max
{
    if(a > b)
        return a;
    else return b;
}
```

primetest-2.c

`/* generally we have different code here than previous one*/`

```
int primtest(int a, int b) //Function for showing the max
{
    if(a > b)
        return a;
    else return b;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "primetest.h"

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    primtest(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

you can compile in below ways

```
gcc main.c primtest.c
```

or

```
gcc main.c primtest-2.c
```